# Doctrine DQL conditional query with Joins

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm trying to build a dynamic query with Doctrine's query builder. I have optional parameters. How would I add this conditionally to the statement?I also have associations (eg, `Service` has many-to-one relation to `Category`)

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('service');
 $qb->join('service.category', 'category');

 $conditions = array();

 if ($categoryId != null) {

        $category = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->find($categoryId);

        if($category == null){
            throw new ApiException('category not found');
        }

        $conditions[] = $qb->expr()->like('category.path', $category->getPath().'%');
    }

 if ($userId != null) {
        $user = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($userId);
        if($user == null){
            throw new ApiException('user not found');
        }

        $conditions[] = $qb->expr()->eq('service.user', $userId);
    }

  if ($rating != null) {
        $conditions[] = $qb->expr()->gte('service.rating', $rating);
    }

 $conditions = call_user_func_array(array($qb->expr(), 'andX'), $conditions);

 $qb->where($conditions);

 $qb->addOrderBy('service.created', 'DESC');

 return $qb;
}
```

When I try to send query

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/services?limit=10&categoryId=45
```

I get following error:

```
Error: Expected StateFieldPathExpression | string | InputParameter | FunctionsReturningStrings | AggregateExpression, got "45" (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: the error looks like related to `$categoryId = 45` but isn't clear, what is the value of the `$category->getPath()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the Literal expression of the given argument. So try this:

```
$conditions[] = $qb->expr()->gte('service.rating', $this->expr()->literal($rating));
```

Instead of this:

```
$conditions[] = $qb->expr()->gte('service.rating', $rating);
```

Hope this help

Comment: `$rating` is a number? why is needed to do this `service.rating > '1'` ?